# wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf to generate PDFs from files with a lot of Javascript content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

Has anyone used wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf files from rails?

wkhtmltopdf ( http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ ) is an c++ executable that the wicked_pdf gem ( https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf ) essentially wraps. It works great for basic pdf generation of tables and reports.

We're now looking to print some pages that have a lot of javascript content. Since the processing is all done server-side, there's obviously no browser to interpret the javascript.

I've been looking around and can see that wkhtmltopdf supports some Javascript, but I'm also seeing that a lot of people are running into problems using it for complex javascript rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a browser engine in there. The WK in wkhtmltopdf stands for webkit which is the browser engine that is used to render HTML and javascript - Chrome uses that engine too.

Do you have a specific thing that does not work? I use javascript and I have seen some quite complex javascript being used as well, for example generation of charts and they have seemed to work good enough. The headers and footers often used with wkhtmltopdf rely heavily on javascipt as well.

I haven't used the ruby gem though.

Comment: Thanks for this note. I resolve the issue some time ago (this post was 4 months ago). I understood that wkhtmltopdf does some javascript processing -- the problem was I had a page that had *a lot* of javascript. wkhtmltopdf couldn't handle it, though it did work for very simple stuff. thanks for the note.

Comment: Great that you figured it out! Did you end using some other tool? I was next going to suggest checking into command line arguments like `--debug-javascript --javascript-delay --no-stop-slow-scripts` but no point anymore :)

Comment: The javascript on the page was very complicated -- one of the items, for example, was getting the Highcharts graphics package working. Highcharts is a javascript-based graphing package that renders charts. wkhtmltopdf just couldn't handle anything that complex. We ended up simplifying the page and taking out most of the javascript.

Comment: This would have been an interesting issue to bite into. I remember seeing a few highcharts+wkhtmltopdf combinations that have been solved with increasing the JS delay - the "delay" actually means how long hte engine waits for wkhtmltopdf to render - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621327 The default 200ms is far too low for things like this.