# highcharts display in my render html page which i want to convert into PDF using wkhtmltopdf in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts, wkhtmltopdf

I have an html page with some text data and graph. I am using wkhtmltopdf gem to generate pdf from html page. Using highcharts, i am generating graph.

> I am able to generate PDF successfully but PDF only contains text
>   data and doesn't have graph in it.

I already tried with some options as below

```
 - plotOptions: { series: { enableMouseTracking: false, shadow: false, animation: false } }, in Hightcharts jquery coding..
```

Please assist me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is it possible to get the full source html or see the page somewhere for testing?

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar w/wkhtmltopdf but I do use wkhtmltoimage to create images of pages that contain graphs from highcharts.  One thing I noticed is that I had to set --javascript-delay to be several seconds long to make sure the chart had enough time to load.  It seems as though wkhtmltopdf does support this option ([wkhtmltopdf v0.10.0_rc2 docs](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html)).  Can you see if that helps?

Here is how we call it w/a javascript delay of 3 seconds:

```
/bin/wkhtmltoimage --javascript-delay 3000 "http://example.com/chartPage" "/path/to/image.png"
```

Comment: can u please paste some code example here which use --javascript-delay?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of this option. It is still valid for the 0.12.0 release currently available in the [github repo](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf) (from source) of wkhtmltopdf.